# Windows Batch File Regular Expression

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

I have a following requirement that needs to be achieved in .bat file. Can some one please help.

There is a string, `ABCD-1234 TEST SENTENCE` in a variable, say **str**. Now I want to check if the string starts with format `[A-Z]*-[0-9] *` or not.

How can I achieve this? I tried various regular expression using `FINDSTR`, but couldn't get the desired result.

**Example:**

```
set str=ABCD-1234 TEST SENTENCE
echo %str% | findstr /r "^[A-Z]*-[0-9] *"
```

Comment: It does work. `C:\Windows\system32>echo ABCD-1234 TEST SENTENCE |  findstr /r "^[A-Z]*-[0-9] *"` which shows `ABCD-1234 TEST SENTENCE` showing it matched.

Comment: FINDSTR regex capabilities are totally non-standard (and crippled). Describe exactly what search criteria you want, and give examples of strings that should match, as well as strings that should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for strings that begin with 1 or more upper case letters, followed by a dash, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by a space.

If the string might contain poison characters like `&`, `<`, `>` etc., then you really should use delayed expansion.

FINDSTR regex is totally non-standard. For example, `[A-Z]` does not properly represent uppercase letters to FINDSTR, it also includes most of the lowercase letters, as well as some non-English characters. You must explicitly list all uppercase letters. The same is true for the numbers.

A space is interpreted as a search string delimiter unless the `/C:"search"` option is used.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(!str!|findstr /rc:"^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*-[0123456789][0123456789]* "
```

You should have a look at [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053)

Comment: Why is it necessary to state `[0123456789]` rather than `[0-9]`? I could not find any wrong (mis-)matches. I am aware of the `[A-Z]` flaw...

Comment: @aschipfl - From a practical standpoint, it is probably not necessary. But there are a few extended ASCII characters that lie within the range `[0-9]`. I believe they represent things like `1/2`, `1/4`, etc. So a precise solution does require `[0123456789]`.

Comment: @aschipfl - You could use `[0123-9]` and still be precise, but it is not something I remember, so I just list all the digits. The `[0-3]` term is equivalent to `[0¼½12²3]`.